# How can I upgrade a PostgreSQL production database using pglogical extension without losing data on the subscriber?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, pglogical

I have a production PostgreSQL database that replicate from publisher to subscriber using pglogical extension. My database is running on postgres 11 and I want to upgrade to postgres 14. I first upgrade the subscriber and then the publisher and start both databases but the replication fail.I have some data on the subscriber database that I do not want to loss if I have to set up a fresh copy from the publisher. My question is how can I upgrade the subscriber and publisher and still keep them in sync?
thanks

upgrade subscriber first and then publisher and start both databases but replication fail

Comment: With what error message does the replication fail?

Comment: the databases (publisher and subscribers) start up as separate databases. I check the status of the subscriber and the status is down. I check the replication slot on the publisher is was no longer available

Comment: Look in the replica log file.  It should have more to say than just "it is down".

Comment: 2023-06-07 08:47:53 EDT,5/0,0,LOG,00000,"starting apply for subscription test_04",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: ERROR,42704,"replication origin ""pgl_ateb_db_01_test_04"" does not exist",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: apply worker [27139] at slot 1 generation 3 exiting with error",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: LOG,00000,"background worker ""pglogical apply 16404:3815206147"" (PID 27139) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0

Comment: "starting apply for subscription test_04",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: ERROR,42704,"replication origin ""pgl_ateb_db_01_test_04"" does not exist",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: EDT,5/0,0,LOG,00000,"apply worker [27222] at slot 1 generation 4 exiting with error",,,,,,,,,"pglogical apply 16404:3815206147","pglogical apply 16404:3815206147",,0

Comment: ,00000,"background worker ""pglogical apply 16404:3815206147"" (PID 27222) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
^C

Comment: those are the errors I see in the logs on the subscriber node

Comment: select * from pg_replication_slots ; on publisher but replication slot still exist but the status is false

Comment: slot_name        |      plugin      | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin |  restart_lsn   | confirmed_flush_lsn
------------------------+------------------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+----------------+---------------------
 pgl_ateb_db_01_test_04 | pglogical_output | logical   |  16404 | ateb     | f         | f      |